# Get concrete URL with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying figuring out how to separate useless information from link with `jsoup`. 
Bunch of code which I should parse here:

```
view-source:https://vk.com/search?c%5Bq%5D=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82&c%5Bsection%5D=communities

public class TestSoup  {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vk.com/smcat").get();
        Elements links;
        //links = doc.select("div > a > img ");
        links = doc.select("[data-src_big]");

        System.out.println(links);
    }
}
```

My output now:

```
<img src="https://pp.vk.me/c636126/v636126727/35e1b/ludjlj7T4i8.jpg" class="ph_img" data-id="-23530818_436648332" data-src_big="https://pp.vk.me/c636126/v636126727/35e1c/a1IyGrtjzUQ.jpg|600|448">
```

Can someone explain how I can extract second link from my output? Many thanks.

Comment: you need to extract this `data-src_big="https://pp.vk.me/c636126/v636126727/35e1c/a1IyGrtjzUQ.jpg|600|448"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-src_big` is *attribute* and each element can have its own value for it.

To iterate over link elements you can use

```
for (Element el : links){
    ..    
}
```

To get value for specified attribute from element you can use

```
el.attr("attrribute_name")
```

If value of attribute is URL address written as relative path like`./foo/bar.jpg` but you want to get it as absolute path like `http://server.com/foo/bar.jpg` you can use

```
el.absUrl("attribute_name")
```

Comment: You beat me to it :) +1

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get both `src` and `data-src_big` from the links found by `div > a > img` using `attr(name)` method:

```
for (Element element : doc.select("div > a > img")) {
    String src = element.attr("src");
    String big = element.attr("data-src_big");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find this in the Jsoup [cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html). In short, you use the `attr` method of Element

```
links = doc.select("[data-src_big]");
String linkStr = links.attr("data-src_big");
```

Note that `links` is of type Elements, and `attr()` just gets the first matching attribute.